# ../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/aggregate_query.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ytly.jpg)
./../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/aggregate_query.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/aggregate_query_snapshot.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/collection_reference.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/document_change.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/document_reference.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/field_value.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/firestore.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/load_bundle_task.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/load_bundle_task_snapshot.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/query.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/query_document_snapshot.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/query_snapshot.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/snapshot_metadata.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/transaction.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/utils/codec_utility.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/src/write_batch.dart: Error: A file can't be part of more than one library.
Try moving the shared declarations into the libraries, or into a new library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_Firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore-4.7.1/lib/cloud_firestore.dart: Context: Used as a part in this library.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.